# Class level variable exposed via self in python

Tags: python

```
class ClassA:
    A = 10
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 10
        self.b = 20

    def methodA(self):
        return self.A

 obj = ClassA()
 print(obj.methodA()) # returns 10
```

This clearly has limitation wherein, I obj will not have an attribute by name "A". But why did python exposes the 'A' via `self.A`. Is it better to return it as `ClassA.A` instead?

Comment: Just a tip - If you are on Python 3.x (which I think you are), then you don't need to have your classes inherit from `object`.  You only did that in Python 2.x so they would become "new style" classes.  However, in Python 3.x, _all_ classes are "new style".

Comment: Thanks @iCodez. Agree and corrected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is entirely by design.

Methods on classes are attributes on the class too (albeit enhanced by being [descriptors](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html) as well). This is how `self.methodA()` would be located too.

Python searches attributes first on the instance, then the class, then the base classes of the class.

Note that *setting* `self.A` will still set the value on the instance, thereby masking the class attribute. This lets classes specify default values for attributes, to be replaced by values on the instance later on.

This all doesn't preclude you from accessing `ClassA.A` directly and bypass the instance dictionary. If you wanted to *change* the shared value, you'd have to assign directly to `ClassA.A` for the above reason.

Comment: I see. Makes sense. What will be the limitation of having a class return it as self.A vs ClassA.A - I think this helps in semantic value for the readers.

Comment: @SenthilKumaran: Sure, you can still do that; making it explicit that you are using a shared value.

Comment: The important difference is that if you return it as `self.A` then subclasses can override it, and as Martijn says instances can have their own value distinct from the class attribute. If you return it as `ClassA.A` then you're explicitly ignoring anything specific to the object or any subclass. So you need to decide whether this is logically a global value that Python happens to make accessible via the object, or an attribute of the instance that Python happens to let you set a class-wide default for. That will tell you which to do.

Comment: Thanks for shedding light on this one @MartijnPieters